# Return a boolean value from a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I want to get a boolean value from a promise.

**Method One**

```
get tokenValid(): Promise<Boolean> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.storage.get('expiresAt')
    .then((expiresAt) => {
      resolve(Date.now() < expiresAt);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(false);
    });
  });
}
```

**Method Two**

```
get tokenValid(): Promise<Boolean> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.storage.get('expiresAt')
    .then((expiresAt) => {
      resolve(Date.now() < expiresAt);
      return Promise.resolve(true); // difference is here
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(false);
      return Promise.reject(false); // difference is here
    });
  });
}
```

**One** and **two** are similar. The difference is in method **Two** there is the return statement either true or false. To get the value, just call the method as

```
if(this.tokenValid()) {
    console.log('return true');
} else {
    console.log('return false');
}
```

**UPDATE:**

By the comments, I modified the methods as

**Method Three**

```
get tokenValid(): Promise<Boolean>() => new Promise((resolve, reject){
     this.storage.get('expiresAt')
    .then((expiresAt) => {
      resolve(Date.now() < expiresAt);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(false);
    });
 }
```

To get the value, just call the method as

```
if(this.tokenValid()) {
    console.log('return true');
} else {
    console.log('return false');
}
```

I understand I have to use `.then()`. But why my method always return true?

Comment: Why do you need to return?  You have the `resolve` and `reject` methods for the returned promise.

Comment: If you want a promise to be resolved to `false` in case of error you need to use `resolve(false)` in catch block. Also you can't get the value immediately `if(this.tokenValid())` makes no sense.

Comment: That's a case where you should *not* use `new Promise`: you already get a promise. Wrapping a promise in a `new Promise` with `resolve` and `reject` calls is adding nothing more to what you already have.

Comment: You can't get the underlying value of the `Promise<Boolean>` in an `if` statement like `this.tokenValid()`. `if(this.tokenValid()) {` will always be truthy. You need to `.then()` or `await` tokenValid to get the underlying value. That's the real issue in the code, not how `true` or `false` is returned.

Comment: this.tokenValid() will return a Promise, not a boolean. When that promise resolves you can get the boolean value. Your method one seems the usual method to work with Promises.

Comment: @BigJ, I disagree with that last phrase. It is an antipattern.

Comment: ↑ No need to make a new promise when you already have a promise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. If I want to return a false value when exception/error, can I use `reject(false)` or I have to use `resolve(false)`?

Comment: It depends entirely if that is a success case for the promise, or if it is an error.  `resolve` is for successes, regardless of the data.  `reject` is for errors.  So if the "operation is a success" and as part of the success it can return true or false, use resolve.  If the value being false means there was an error with the operation, reject it

Comment: Updated the question, if it is still duplicated, please let me know so I would delete the question.